# boto3: generate_presigned_url get access denied during upload

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm testing to generate pre-signed URL to upload files to S3. I have no issues generating the signed URL, but and I'm getting AccessDenied error when attempting to upload it.

I've summarised my issue to the following code for testing.

**Source code**

```
import boto3
import os
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
def list_files():
    print("Listing files in bucket:")
    bucket = boto3.resource('s3').Bucket(bucket_name)
    for obj in bucket.objects.all():
        print(" - "+obj.key)

bucket_name = "asf-bucket"

list_files()

key= "test.py"
print (" Generating pre-signed url...")
url=s3.generate_presigned_url('put_object', Params={'Bucket':bucket_name, 'Key':key}, ExpiresIn=3600, HttpMethod='PUT')
command="curl --request PUT --upload-file {} {}".format(key, url)
print(command)
print (" Uploading with curl ...")
os.system(command)
```

**Script Output**

```
$ python3 test.py
Listing files in bucket:
 - Dropped text.txt
 Generating pre-signed url...
curl --request PUT --upload-file test.py https://asf-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/test.py?AWSAccessKeyId=----&Signature=----&Expires=----
 Uploading with curl ...
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>A0E4587FFEB9F1EE</RequestId><HostId>kvfkV7YdDmtNNCSfWAjDTdZ/8+y2HrfcXSseQPlrq0300vjg9zYe1H0Qidsqf7kcBIieUGoXoUA=</HostId></Error>
```

Tested with AWS root account. I've get the same error.

**CORS configuration**

```
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

What I'm missing?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html

**Update - Adding content type**

Following @kichik advice I added the content type with no changes on the current behaviour

```
url=s3.generate_presigned_url('put_object', Params={'Bucket':bucket_name, 'Key':key, 'ContentType':'text/plain'}, ExpiresIn=3600, HttpMethod='PUT')
command="curl --header \"Content-Type: text/plain\" --request PUT --upload-file {} {}".format(key, url)
```

Comment: Try setting `Content-Type` in both the signed URL and the `curl` command to be the same thing.

Comment: Tested and it did not had any effect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything was alright, the mistake was not escaping the URL on the shell.

So instead of

```
curl --request PUT --upload-file test.py https://asf-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/test.py?AWSAccessKeyId=----&Signature=----&Expires=----
```

Do

```
curl --request PUT --upload-file test.py 'https://asf-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/test.py?AWSAccessKeyId=----&Signature=----&Expires=----'
```